# gstreamer pipeline video AND audio

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer

I am very new to gstreamer and have a pipeline that parses a H.261 encoded video file fine with the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=trailer.mp4 ! 
qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0! queue ! h264parse ! omxh264dec !
nveglglessink -e
```

Now the video shows fine but this file also has audio encoded with `MPEG-4 AAC`. Can someone tell me how I may modify the pipeline to also decode the audio stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=trailer.mp4 ! 
qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse ! omxh264dec !
nveglglessink demux.audio_0 ! queue ! aacparse ! faad ! autoaudiosink -e`

Should do the trick? If you haven't installed the `faad` decoder plugin you can try `avdec_aac` if you have installed the libav plugins. But you will need an AAC decoder plugin, thats for sure.

Comment: Thanks! That did the job. Although when it initializes there is a loud click initially. I do not know where that comes from!